# How to record machine restart time using Python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reboot

I am writing code on my machine and running this code over the vm using rpyc connection:

```
import os
import time

start_time = time.time()
cmd = "sudo shutdown -r now"
returned_value = os.system(cmd)
print(f"returned value is {returned_value}")
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

The problem is as soon as the vm shutdowns' the program exits. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you run your shutdown program from outside the vm?  For example your script could use vmware or virtualbox (or whatever) commands to shutdown the vm and record the times you want without being murdered when the VM is shut down.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. I am running code in my dev env which is on my own machine and  my VM(10.15 mac machine in vmware fusion) is my client where I am supposed to run my automation code to reboot.

Comment: The suggestion is to invoke `vmrun reset <path_to_vmx_file>` from your host OS, instead of running `sudo shutdown -r now` from within the vm.  The benefit of doing that is the shutdown/reboot control occurs outside the vm, enabling you to record metadata without the control script going down with the vm.

Comment: oh but eventually the vm is going to be in vsphere (VMware could)